# Which instruments can a 4e Bard use as an implement?

Tags: dnd-4e, bard, implements

I have a player who is starting a Bard in a new 4e game. He (and I) were wondering which musical instruments could be used in place of a wand. I found this passage:

> Songblades and some magic musical
>   instruments can be used as implements
>   for bard powers and bard paragon path
>   powers. Bards treasure these magic
>   musical instruments not only for the
>   power they offer, but for the wondrous
>   melodies they produce in the hands of
>   a skilled musician.

However it doesn't clarify *which* musical instruments. Just looking for some clarification - thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the musical instrument magic items are flutes, lutes, harps, horns, lyres, sitars, mandolins, bandores and drums. They are usually listed under wondrous items and will clearly say that a bard can use them as an implement and how they are used as such. You can find them in the PHB2.

Answer (score 1):

If you go through the PHB2 in the list of magical instruments only the string instruments have the property listed as being able to be used by bards as implements